# Angular/NgRx Unit testing can't create TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

While developing a component that requires and NgRx store the testing suite fails and I get a message stating that...

'Can't resolve all parameters for NavComponent: (?).'

```
  ● AppComponent › should create the app

    Can't resolve all parameters for NavComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:69:33)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:69:27)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:57:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:362:27)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:160:66)
      at src/app/app.component.spec.ts:32:8
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
```

My test bed config

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let router: Router;
  let location: Location;
  let store: MockStore<ApplicationState>;
  const initialState: ApplicationState = {
    root: {
      user: null,
      tabs: null
    }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes), MaterialsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent, NavComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState })]
    }).compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    store = TestBed.get<Store<ApplicationState>>(Store);

    router.initialNavigation();
  });
```

The Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'af3-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs$: Observable<NavTab[]>;
  constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.ApplicationState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.tabs$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.selectTabsForUserState));
  }
}
```

I have also tried to import StoreModule, but according to [ngrx.io](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing), that isn't necessary as `provideMockStore()` setups up all the providers necessary with configuring the reducers.

The error and the stack trace aren't very helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: it turns out that the test bed can't inject ANY referenced services. I created a test service and tried to run the test, but received the same errors when running the tests.

UPDATE: NGRX is definitely not the issue. To add some more context I have been trying to track this issue down. Currently no providers can be resolved. I replace Jasmine with Jest and it looks like Jest may be the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I don't think that NGRX is the problem there. Maybe do you have missing polyfile

Comment: @Wandrille. NGRX is definitely not the issue. To add some more context I have been trying to track this issue down. Currently no providers can be resolved. I replace Jasmine with Jest and it looks like Jest may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` to `tsconfig.spec.json` was the solution for me.

Reference: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/288